# Typescript can't cast abstract function array, results in error, why?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Typescript throws an error for this code(abstracted- not the real code) :

```
export const enum typeList {
    a = "aa",
    b = "bb",
    c = "cc"
}

export interface parameterEvent<S extends typeList> {
    "kind": S;
    "detail": DetailTypes[S];
}

export interface DetailTypes {
    [typeList.a]: string;
    [typeList.b]: boolean;
    [typeList.c]: undefined;
}

interface returnTypes {
    [typeList.a]: number | string;
    [typeList.b]: number;
    [typeList.c]: boolean;
}

type Universial<T extends typeList> = (event: parameterEvent<T>) => returnTypes[T];

type collection = {
    [T in typeList]: Universial<T>[];
};

const universialGroup: collection = {
    [typeList.a]: [],
    [typeList.b]: [],
    [typeList.c]: []
};

export function addToUniversalGroup<T extends typeList>(kind: T, val: Universial<T>): void {
    const listeners = universialGroup[kind] as Universial<T>[];
}
```

Error:

> Conversion of type 'collection[T]' to type 'Universial[]' may be a
> mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If
> this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. Type
> 'Universial<typeList.a>[] | Universial<typeList.b>[] |
> Universial<typeList.c>[]' is not comparable to type 'Universial[]'.
> Type 'Universial<typeList.c>[]' is not comparable to type
> 'Universial[]'. Type 'Universial<typeList.c>' is not comparable to
> type 'Universial'. Type 'boolean' is not comparable to type
> 'returnTypes[T]'.

[**This example on TypescriptLang**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&target=0&jsx=0&module=1&ts=3.9.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM72MgrgWzjATzGABkBLdOAbwFgAoORuAQzgF44AiZ5zgGnpM4AI3Zdhw-oKYIxnBAk70AvvXqhIsOGWQxgUAGbMEwOGGZRmOYHqgBRAG6YYAHgDKcUHuQATVPiJSChgAPmppRk4Aax0fTgAuODcAbgiuHxtmMgAbBLgAEUycgBVA1ABtNwBdVLpVOnVwaHgdWyMTAqLs0uJ-WgYmcsJicnQAOmYqxPQoHQBzWqEhwNGYMeEpkQgIbOBmZEXB4aDxhE2sX2ADHWAfWvr6Vv120ygbLChkHuA+tOWR4ITTbYHDCfRwAA+cBm80OjH+JzWG0SILBUDhcARqzGZ0Swm2u329zUdGOcAAqsgyE4oKgyMxsi5ip4QN4-AEAegwhwABTAJy6RLmSzWWyOZxMkIASnYYTeMA+XzK5WKNRJZKQ2V2CBgZBQYn6S2ZOg5iM2lOp+jpDMl5TVdVq9CQaHgF0ttPp2QA4lAIFgwIlNdrdfqOIajitAZNEnaBAN4cdscjMVU40tE4DcSmVI66BpmnADBcdXrkCwfD5ihALTTUAyfX6wEyWWz-BmuTyYr5EsU+HAHAzEjWrZ7JVLEg4IGQfOF44gUJRssFMFaxG7a56G-7yl2fFUWP5hx6bcUQnb7kA)

One interesting fact is that removing `event: parameterEvent<T>` from the Universal type fixes this error which doesn't make sense IMHO.

I'm trying to understand what is wrong with this example? Why do I get this error message?

Comment: Thanks for the input :) Going back to any is not an option for us. The string or number thing is just something from the abstraction i did and is way different in the real code. It does not effect the real problem with this example.

Comment: An idea on how to solve this problem, maybe somebody experienced the same thing, has an idea or knows this is a known bug of typescript or something in that direction.

Comment: Well i'm not waiting for typescript to change. That would obviously be pointless. 
I'm trying to understand what is wrong with the example and telling me to fix my types doesn't help me in any way. As said that this example is an abstraction to just show the error that i don't understand and has not to much in common with the real code ;)

Comment: I've added an actual question into your question. Hopefully that shows what your actually wanting from this question?